# solving for a variable in an equation with a modulo

Tags: python, modulo, algebra

new to python, bad at math.

im trying to make a program where you input variables into the equation (x*y-z)%4==0. i have:

```
x=int(input())
y=int(input())
z=int(input())
if (x*y-z)%4==0:
   print("Yes")
else:
   print("No")
```

my question is, let's say i know y and z, but want to solve for x.
i know enough algebra to solve for this if the %4 wasn't there:

```
x*y-z=0
x*y=z
x=z/y
```

so would it just be x=z/y%4? that doesn't seem right?

Comment: This is a [math.se] question, not programming.

Comment: There's no unique solution when you have modulus. For instance, suppose the equation were `x % 4 == 0`. The solutions are all multiples of 4.

Comment: If you require the solution to be an integer, this is an example of a Diophantine Equation. Google it.

Comment: thank you for your help. im new to all of this and didnt know there was a separate mathematics section.
yes, i basically want to assure that whatever you put in for x, y, and z, the answer will be divisible by 4. i didnt know if there was a simpler way to find a range of x where this is true if only y and z are known. ill look into the diophantine equation!